# Write an asynchrone IResoureHandler for CefSharp

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cefsharp

I have written my own ResourceHandler. ProcessRequest() works asynchrone. After updating CefSharp from 43 (WPF) to 49 (WinForms) I have some problems with IRequest.IsDisposed.

It seems that the request is disposed before my Task is started. And if the request is disposed I have no more access to the post data.

```
public class MySchemeHandler : IResourceHandler {
  // ...

  public bool ProcessRequest(IRequest request, ICallback callback) {
    // copy request???
    Task.Run(() => {
      try {

        if (request.IsDisposed == true) // Copy post data before Task.Run()???
          throw new ExpressDisposedException();

        // ...
        // Process(request, callback);

      } catch(Exception ex) {
        callback.Cancel();
      } finally {
        callback.Dispose();
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
}
```

So is there a way to avoid the disposing of IRequest. Is anywhere a complete example how to make it better.

Comment: As per the `Release Notes` for `49.0.0` you should implement `ResourceHandler` now, as the `IResourceHandler` interface exposes the underlying `CEF API`. here is an example https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/FlashResourceHandler.cs

Comment: As for `IRequest` being disposed, you need to read the values from it before spawning off your `Task`.

Comment: If you need more info on the changes then I suggest you read the `Release notes` on `GitHub`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is a typical requirement to use the request in the Task. So I thought there would be a common workaround  to "make a copy" of IRequest or to "dispose later". By now I have my own mechanism to make a deep copy of IRequest. And of course it works ;-)

Comment: Behavior was changed in the rewrite as the code was greatly simplified. By all means submit a `Pull Request` that delays disposal of `IRequest`, should only be `5-6` lines of code. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1597 for the source changes.